# checking if user inputted string is in dictionary if it is return the value

Tags: python, pandas, quandl

I am writing a stock price predictor program where the user inputs the company they wish to predict for and how many days in the future the program should then search a dictionary in which a quandl CSV file with company names and company ticker names inside. The full names have been assigned to keys and the ticker names have been assigned to its respective key. What I want to do is check for partial matches on the user inputted string in the dictionary(keys) and then return the value of the key. Here is the code I have so far but it does not work 100% it tells me there are no matches in the dictionary.

```
#download dependancies and import packages
import quandl as quandl #module for getting the financial data
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import csv
import pandas as pd
cnames= pd.read_csv('secwiki_tickers.csv')
cnamesDict= pd.Series(cnames.Ticker.values, index=cnames.Name).to_dict()

#Get the company name user want to predict numbers for and check against the (cnamesDict)
user_cname = input("Which company would you like to predict stock prices for?\n")
def searchForName(dictToSearch, lookup):
  for key, value in dictToSearch.items():
     for v in value:
      if lookup in v:
        return value




print(searchForName(cnamesDict, user_cname))
```

When I type in "Facebook" it tells me there a none matches. Any help is much appreciated 
also here is a link to the csv file [CSV LINK](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13MNnFa6EiY_dnlwZ_wXOVNATpR5vsBdI)

Answer (score 0):

What if you type 'Facebook, Inc.' since that is the name in the CSV you supplied?